# Удаление ведущих пробелов в строке при выводе через printf()

Tags: c, строки, printf

Здравствуйте.

Вопрос: есть ли способ вывести строку без ведущих пробелов, используя исключительно `printf()`? То есть без предварительного ее изменения и вообще без какого-либо лишнего кода, вроде по-буквенного вывода?

*Зачем оно мне? - перевожу приложение, в котором к исходной строке прибавляется какое-то неизвестное кол-во пробелов и из-за этого она ужасно выглядит в русской локализации. Доступ имею только к строке формата, вроде "`Param: %@, another param:%s, ...`"*.
Спасибо.

UPD.
Забыл уточнить:

**строка формата:** " %@ %@ KB %@ %@";
**на выходе:** "`______Software Update_____28 471 KB____3_files`" (где "_" это пробел).
Т.е. где-то в коде есть макрос вида `LocalizedFormat(format, __VA_ARGS__)`, где `format` - та самая строка формата (берется из внешнего файла, который я редактирую).

Comment: Увы, нету такого. Если не нарушает красоту (таблицы, допустим), то можно вывод обрабатывать на предмет подчистки, напр: `yourgreatprogramm | sed -e 's,\s\+, ,g'`

Comment: Очень жаль. Просто мне дана только сама строка формата, которая подставляется в уже работающее приложение. Ну и приложение GUI'йное, так что никакой пост-обработки.

Comment: Достаточно просто передать указатель на первый символ-не-пробел.

Comment: Или используя "find_first_of" из библиотеки string.

Comment: @mikillskegg & @Asen ... имея доступ только к содержимому форматной строки.

Comment: В вопросе говорится о **неизвестном** количестве пробелов. Интересно, откуда они берутся ?

Или все таки в каждом из форматов разное, но определенное количество пробелов в начале ? Если второе, то интересно, как отреагирует GUI, если заменить их на '\\r' (возврат каретки) ? Или (если пробелов в формате нет) в начало выводимого текста '\\r' добавить, или несколько '\\b' ...

--

Автор, а приведите несколько форматов и Ваших текстов, которые по ним печатаются. Может, что путное в голову придет.

Comment: Ну если гуй отрабатывает backspace, то кто его знает.

Comment: Я попробовал в GnomeTerminal ubuntu и в консоли виндоуз '\\r' в начале текста, выводимого по формату "%40s", т.е. текст позиционируется вправо в поле из 40 символов. 

Так вот, все **перед** '\\r' *исчезает*, текст после '\\r' выводится с начала строки.

Попробуйте.

Comment: Впервые вижу '@' в C форматах, как символ редактирования. Вы уверены, что форматирование не производится какой-то собственной функцией, по неизвестным нам правилам ?

Comment: @avp это Objective-C, а %@ - тип для строковых объектов. Правила известны - такие же как у printf().

Comment: Возможно, помогут [уязвимости](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Format_String.pdf), то есть передача выполнения кода на сторону.

Comment: @cool это несколько не мой случай - все, что я могу сделать - это как-то изменить саму строку формата. Да и то, это будет костыль, но пока разработчик не торопится что-то менять, так что этот вариант был бы неплох.

Comment: В C printf("==%40s==",XAXA); выведет 

    ==*36пробелов*XAXA==

 а printf("==%-40s==",XAXA); выведет 

    ==XAXA*36пробелов*==

Могу лишь (по аналогии) предложить попробовать заменить %@ на %-@.

К сожалению, с Objective-C не знаком, попробовать не на чем.

Comment: @avp увы, не работает. Видимо, придется все таки ждать фиксов от разработчика.  
Спасибо всем за советы.

Answer (score 1):

[@VioLet](/users/852/violet), увы-увы... увы лимит комментариев исчерпал. Поэтому в ответе не ответ, а одна идея (догадка) по поводу Вашей проблемы.

Если Вы делаете русский текст в кодировке UTF-8, а программа форматирования по @ не знает о многобайтных кодировках, то она может рассчитывать размер выходного поля по количеству байт выводимой строки (объекта). Отсюда и пробелы.

В этом случае можно попробовать однобайтную кодировку русского языка (cp1251, iso8859-5 или koi8-r) и должным образом описать локализацию. Например (для *nix) попробовать export LANG=...

Или что-то иное, но в направлении управления кодировкой.

Comment: Да нет, что вы, пробелы специально подставляются приложением, чтобы сделать "красивый" по-колоночный вывод в текстовое поле.

Comment: Сочувствую. Переводить а английского на русский с сохранением длины текста -- просто развлечение для мазохистов.

Comment: @alexlz Ладно бы еще одно это. Так нужно еще конструкцию "XX file/files" превратить в "файлов: ХХ". Из-за одного этого вся таблица летит к чертям. Ну а использовать "XX файл(-а/-ов)" не хочется..

Comment: Теперь все понятно. Без переделки приложения (возможности редактирования как форматов, так и текстов сообщений) не обойтись.

Comment: @avp И тексты переводить можно, но да, вы правы, выглядит это все убого. 
Еще раз спасибо всем, закрываю вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько правильно я понял вашу задачу, то могу посоветовать сделать так:

```
...
#include<string>
...
int main()
{
    string str("     sdfsdf sdfsdf  213123      sfd");
    string::size_type i;
    i = str.find_first_not_of(" ");
    str = str.substr(i);
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

Comment: Браво! Но если у него не получится, может быть Вы сами это сделаете? Разницы-то никакой, что на C++ играть, что в вувузелы дуть.

Comment: "есть ли способ вывести строку без ведущих пробелов, используя исключительно printf()....без предварительного ее изменения..".

Comment: А можно задать(ненавязчивый!) вопрос? А почему именно "printf()" ?

Comment: Потому что в нем используется точно такая же система форматирования текста при выводе.